# 'You must have at least one calendar activated under My calendars. Do you want to open the calendar list?' after disabling/deleting calendar app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calendar

I used the CleanMaster app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 to disable apps I do not use.  I then accidentally deleted my calendar. When I want to add an event, I get a notification:

> You must have at least one calendar activated under My calendars. Do you want to open the calendar list?

When I hit OK, I just get the blank calendar list.

I have now also downloaded the 'Business Calendar' app - but this also notifies me that I have no calendars selected.

How do I reinstall or reactive my calendar then?

Comment: What calendar was it? A "local one" (not synced anywhere), or a Google-synced calendar?

Comment: Have you tried installing [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It's easy to fix:

1. Go to settings/more/application manager
2. swipe left to get to "disabled"
3. Click on "calendar storage"
4. click "enable"

All your calendar entries should now re-appear.